# Given x,y,z data of a periodic object, calculate the period of the object (if possible)

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, interpolation

So the problem I am working on is as such. Given the x,y,z data of a periodic object over time (from the origin in 3d space) (need not be uniform), calculate the period of the object (if the data given is periodic and the calculation is possible).

So the best idea I have been able to come up with so far, is to use some form of interpolation to get a function for the data, but I am not sure how I would go about using the function to calculate the period. Also, if interpolation is the best way forward, would using cubic spline interpolation work?

Finally, since the data given is 3d, and so far all the experience I have is working with 2d data for interpolation, if I was to use cubic splines to interpolate, how would the actual implementation work?